# productRepository->getCustomAttribute('attribute_code');

Tags: magento-2.1, attributes, repository

I need to retrieve 1 product attribute value from 1 product, I wonder if using the product repository in this way is the most effective in terms of performances:

```
$productColour = $this->productRepository->get($this->getSku())->getCustomAttribute('colour');
```

thanks

Comment: In which file you are using such code ?

Comment: @KishanPatadia in a custom block Adminhtml\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Name.php. Basically, I have to show this attribute value in the sales_order_view template under the product_name column

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$_product_Object = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface')->getById(1);
$colorType = $_product_Object->getResource()->getAttribute('colour')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product_Object);
```

Comment: should not the object manager use avoided?